# Do we need the 'point-rotation' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 3 questions tagged 'point-rotation': 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-rotation

Do you see any value in this tag? Or should we remove it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not clear that any of those questions have any similarity - I'd say delete.

Comment: The way to do that is to remove all references to the tag; the site will automatically delete the tag after some interval of disuse.  (The community cannot actually delete any tags.)

Comment: @whuber says above that the community cannot actually delete any tags so I am wondering if that means the moderators cannot either.  If that is the case, perhaps we can create a tag called deprecated-tag and make tags with no clear use synonyms of that.  Removing all references may be practical when a tag to be "deprecated" has only been used a handful of times.

Comment: @PolyGeo Good idea--worth trying.  Yes, I always include moderators when mentioning our "Community": we are all part of it and neither separate from nor above it.